# Workbench moderation state tab not displayed

Tags: users, workbench

My "Authenticated User" can *not* see the tab "Publishing options" on the node/add/[content type] page. What I need in my workflow is the user to select the moderation state (Draft/Moderation) the node should be in, but he can't see the tab.

I have 3 moderation states: `Draft`, `In Moderation`, `Published`.
[image: Screenshot as admin]

The user has the following permissions:

```
Node:
    View published content
    View own unpublished content
    View content revisions
    create [content type] content
    edit own [content type] content
    edit any [content type] content
Workbench Moderation:
    View the moderation messages on a node
    Use "My Drafts" workbench tab
    View all unpublished content
    View moderation history
```

I configured the permissions looking at https://www.drupal.org/node/1175592 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nqWLrxH_4M + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHYWOohhKZE

I don't know if there are other permissions that I forgot. I have already rebuilt the permissions on /admin/reports/status/rebuild, no difference.

Funny thing is that, if I assign *all permissions*

```
Moderate all content from Draft to in Moderation
Moderate all content from in Moderation to Draft
Moderate all content from in Moderation to Published
```

to the anonymous user, he still *can't* see this tab.

Any help welcome.

Comment: Did you try doing this on a clean install? What is the setup of the site on which you're trying to do this (e.g. any other moderation/administration modules installed, content/field access modules, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean by normal user? Is it authenticated user? Can you please post the screenshot in english language if possible?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to make it a bit more understandable. Switched to English screenshot. The open tab `Publishing options` is the one that I can not see as `authenticated user`

Comment: @Topsitemakers many modules installed & activated, yes. Drupal 7.30/PHP5.4/MySQL; No other moderation modules are installed. Many, many modules, but no other access modules at all. only panel/display suite. But that's not the problem IMHO. we had had workflow/revisioning installed, but wiped them because of their huge complexity. Workbench is simpler, fullfills our needs, the only thing that does NOT work is this issue here.

Comment: Did you try to replicate the issue on a clean install? I can't test this right now, doing this from start might give you a clue where's the issue.

Comment: added some additional info. more permissions do not help.

Comment: @Topsitemakers I'll try from a fresh install.

Comment: I installed a fresh D7, enabled Workbench, Workbench Moderation, Views, Chaos Tools, aded `page` content type (enabled *Create new revision*, * Enable moderation of revisions*, default moderation state *needs review*). Added user *tester*, set all permissions according to written above. Logged in as that *tester* user, click on /node/add/page - scroll down - there is NO tab for choosing the moderation state! He gets a message "Your draft will be placed in moderation" as this is the default. But he can not change it.

Comment: Now **this** is funny. In my fresh install, everything works as intended if I assign the "Draft to Moderation" and "moderation to Draft" Workbench moderation permission to the authenticated user. But with the same permissions I can't reproduce this on my real site. There must be something with another module. Is there a way I can debug this (on a hosted system?) Any hints?

Comment: Found the solution. I can't answer my own question within 8 hours, StackExchange says. I had wiped the tab using PHP. Clear shoot into my own foot. Will add the answer when I may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Again, Fooled myself - it was a simple shoot into my own foot.
I had written custom PHP code in my costom theme in the function THEME_form_alter() to **suppress** the whole revisoning tab:

```
$form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

When I then installed and configured the workbench module I didn't realize that it needs exactly THIS tab.

Works as expected now. Sorry for using your time... But maybe someone else learns from my errors...
Thanks for  your thoughts.